# Proper collections in ZFC

Tags: soft-question, set-theory, model-theory

Consider a fixed model $M$ of ZFC or ZF.

A "set" $s$ in $M$ is a single element of $M$'s universe. One can identify a
collection of sets (i.e. collection of elements of $M$'s universe, as seen from
outside of $M$, in the meta-theory) with $s$ by collecting all sets that
are contained in $s$ according to $\in_M$.  A "proper class" is a collection of
elements of $M$'s universe (outside of $M$, in the meta-theory) which is identified by some formula, but not identified by any set of $M$.

Following this pattern, one can introduce the concept of "proper collection"
as some collection of elements of $M$'s universe which is not identified by any formula.

I would argue that proper collections have to exist in a model that is large                                                                                                                                                     enough in the meta-theory.

Are there any interesting theorems that refer to proper collections?

Comment: In the metatheory, any countable model $M$ has uncountably many subsets of elements and there are only countably many formulas, so you're correct that proper collections have to exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at forcing (over a separative partial order). A generic filter cannot be defined in the ground model by any formula (even with parameters), so this is an example of what you’re calling a proper collection.

Another example is $0\#$; if it exists, it’s a proper collection of $L.$